# connect to firefox with C#

Tags: c#, javascript, firefox

Sory for the title and the topic, I didn't really know where to put my question :) .
I'm looking for a way to automatically get the HTML source of an openned page in firefox so I can use it in a C# application. For example, I would browse a page in firefox. When I would like to get some data I would start my program and refresh the page in firefox. The program would get the HTML source and extract data.
Kinda like clicking the "show source" in firefox, using Ctrl+a and pasting the source into my C# application, but I want to automate this step.
I hope there is another way than to writing my own firefox extension, I never did that before and it would take long for me. Too long just to get the source.

I'm already using Greasemonkey, so I could write a script that automatically saves the source to a file from which my application could read the whole source. But that  wouldn't be effective.
Unless there is another way to connect to the firefox page via javascript, that won't work.

Ok, to put it short : which way is the best to automatically get the HTML source of an opened page in firefox to my C# application?

I'm gratefull for any answers :)

Comment: You'll have to write some kind of extension, how else are you going to determine which firefox window/tab to use?

Comment: May I ask why you want to follow that approach? No offense, but most of the time, there really is a better solution around the corner...

Comment: Well, I usually fetch the source of a page directly. I normally use firefox to browse the internet and it would be practical if I'd have a way of quickly sending the source code to my application since the page is already open. This can be done for internet explorer, but C# doesn't support XPCOM directly so I would have to write an extension that uses a C++ library. This way I could send the source code via named pipes to my C# application. But as I already said, it's a little overkill just for getting the HTML source. I was hoping for an easier solution. If there isn't any I'll use ctrl+a :D

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write my comment clearly. I had a C++ DLL in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be firefox? The IE browser functions integrate pretty well and easy with windows forms .NET applications. Is something like that a good idea for you? (check out the WebBroweser.Document property at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document(v=VS.85).aspx)